# How to receive single quote JSON in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, single-quotes

I am writing an API to consume data from another 3rd party application (RapidPro). Sadly, the third party application sends its JSon enclosed in single quotes which Laravel does not seem to understand, when I return the `$request` object, I get an empty array [].

Is there any way I can accept the JSon as it is with single quotes as I cannot possibly change the third party API?

The JSon to parse is this one:

```
{
    'contact': {
        'uuid': 'e65ef92b-24ce-459b-a8fd-beb042330eb0',
        'name': 'UserName',
        'urn': 'tel: +12000000000'
    },
    'flow': {
        'name': 'MyFlow',
        'uuid': 'da5d6c42-a818-481b-b91c-e9622dafe8be'
    },
    'path': [],
    'results': {},
    'run': {
        'uuid': '2a2f709f-d114-413c-a865-d960cea73981',
        'created_on': '2018-05-23T19: 06: 03.308191+00: 00'
    },
    'input': {
        'urn': 'tel: +12000000100',
        'text': 'What I wanna say',
        'attachments': []
    }
}
```

I user the following route in receiving the API call, it works and takes it to the controller:

```
Route::post('sms', 'UserController@sms')->name('sms.store');
```

The SMS controller for this demo let's just write it to a local file and send back the results to be viewed in Insomnia where the demo call is made:

```
public function sms(Request $request)
    {
        Storage::put('sms.txt', $request);
        return $request;

    }
```

When I post the JSON in via Insomnia to my server I get an empty response, when I use double quotes however; the posted JSON is thrown back nicely.

Comment: Show them http://json.org/

Comment: @Kyslik as in making them adhere to standards?

Comment: can you show us some code? there shouldn't be any problem with single quotes.

Comment: @GonrasKarols Let me edit the question to add the route and the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, in RapidPro debugger the jSON is shown using single-quotes but in actual POST it uses double quotes. What I had wrong was the AUTH. I had to include some header for Laravel's Basic Once authentication.